# $(window).bind('beforeunload' not working when calling a function first

Tags: javascript

I have tried using this script:

```
<script>

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
   checkin();
    return "Do you really want to leave now?";
});

function checkin() {
    alert("test");
}
```

it will only work when I remove the call of checkin function. But what i needed to do is call a function before leaving the page. what should i do?

Comment: return checkin() ?????

Comment: refer to this question. It might help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010326/cant-change-location-of-webpage-using-window-onbeforeunload

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal its not working also

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function on beforeunload event of window.
But it'll not allow you to alert something. 
Write console.log instead of alert and check.

And as the concole.log is running, so then function is being executed and you can do whatever you want in that checkin() function.