# How to close a page before the page refresh?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

Does anybody know on how to close the tab before the page refresh or if the refresh triggers?

I already tried this one

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
     open(location, '_self').close();
});
```

but, it's not firing unless you use return in beforeunload

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return "Do you really want to reload this page?"
    //There's a popup that says the string return above.
});
```

So I tried to use this one

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return closeTab();
});

function closeTab(){
    //close functions
}
```

Actually, there's no problem with closing, the problem here is I can't call a function before refreshing.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Here I found a probably duplicate issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185965/window-bindbeforeunload-not-working-when-calling-a-function-first

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh I found another way to solve my problem. Thanks! :D